# Edit stderr before writing it to file together with stdout

Tags: bash, shell, date, stderr

I went through many SO questions but so far I couldn't find one that addresses my particular problem.

I use GNU date to convert dates into epoch times:

```
date -f created_at +%s > created_at_epoch
```

To catch error messages like "date: invalid date ‘...’" I redirect stderr to stdout:

```
date -f created_at +%s 2>&1 > created_at_epoch
```

Now, I would like to change the error message into something like "NA". I tried process substitution but this doesn't seem to work. The order of the lines in the output is changed and the process doesn't finish.

```
date -f created_at +%s 2> >(sed s/^date.*/NA/ >&1) > created_at_epoch
```

I would be very glad for any suggestions on how to solve this, I am not getting my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first redirect standard error to standard output, then manipulate the combined stream:

```
date -f created_at +%s |& sed '/date/s/.*/NA/' > created_at_epoch
```

`|&` is a Bash shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

Comment: Thank you very much for having a look at this! That's the solution that I am using at the moment. I thought that it may be a bit inefficient because sed has to to check every line and I expect only a very small fraction (way less than 1%) to be corrupted, that's why I tried it the whole process substition thing. There is probably no way to avoid the repeated checking? Is it maybe possible to create a more efficient regex?

Comment: @maxpe Is it actually slow? How big is `created_at`, and what format are the dates in there?

Comment: It's not very much slowing down everything, was just wondering... The dates are in this format : "Sun Jan 11 03:29:55 +0000 2009" and I have around 7.5 billion of them.

Comment: @maxpe *Maybe* it would be faster if you filtered out invalid dates first, but I can't think of a solution that uses `date -f` and doesn't require to look at every line with another tool if you need the `NA` lines in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would use the process substitution method you tried, but I wouldn't here since you care about output order and there's no guarantee in general that stdout and stderr will be correctly intermingled. You don't want to rely on them both being line buffered and being flushed regularly.

It would be better to process each line separately yourself. That way you can control exactly how bad dates are handled. As a bonus, you can suppress stderr entirely and just key off of `date`'s exit code.

```
while IFS= read -r date; do
    date -d "$date" +%s 2>/dev/null || echo "N/A"
done <created_at >created_at_epoch
```

Comment: Ah, I think this is cleaner in that it guarantees the output sequence. Might be slower for many dates, though, as it calls `date` once per line instead of just once with `-f`.

Comment: Thank you for reply! That's really a clean solution, I will check out how the speed is compared to date -f (I have to convert billions of dates). Just for curiosity: How would I do the process substitution above correctly? Do I have to turn off buffering beforehand? This will probably cost a lot of speed then, because I run several instances of this script at the same time.